# Quartz Scheduler clustering: Is there a way to run the SAME job uniquely and delay the next firing till that same job completes

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have implemented Quartz Scheduler with clustering with one jdbcstore.

I have a job QzJob1 which is CRON scheduled for every two minutes. but the job runs for 3 minutes of total execution time.

I know the nodes will pickup the jobs based on the trigger time when they are available.

So let us say, The QzJob1 is running in NODE1 at 10:00 AM but it completes at 10:03 AM. Now for the same job the trigger is available at 10:02 AM its been picked up by another node which is NODE2. It is this default behaviour I know.

Now my ask is. Is there a way to make this unique across all nodes so that till that job completes it will not be triggered again though the trigger is ready before it completes.

I tried to find out it but could not get anywhere. So please guide/instruct/point me so that I will take it forward.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: what is the quartz version you are using ?  see https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03.html

Comment: @PrasadU, It is 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT. Thank you for the url. It has the details for concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your job implementation class with @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation. For details, see https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html.

Comment: You are right, I missed this as I was looking in the clustering documents only. Thank you for pointing me out. I will check this and come back.